# How to structure Pydev project for version control with GitLab?

Tags: python, eclipse, gitlab, pydev, egit

I'm using Eclipse with PyDev and EGit plugin to manage my projects. All my current projects are stored as PyDev projects with the source code stored as Python pacakges in a src folder:

[image]

I want to clean up my code and use GitLab for version control. I have created a new project under my GitLab profile:

[image]

I have then imported the GitLab project (repository) into Eclipse via Egit:

[image]

I then created a new PyDev project in Eclipse with a new Python package called geoHydro and selected the newly imported GitLab repository. I then commited and pushed the changes to my GitLab remote repository:

[image]
**Initial commit and push to GitLab repository**

[image]

**Pydev project under version control**

[image]

**Hierarchy of project structure in GitLab**

I don't understand why there are repeated geoHydro folders, surely the Pydev project folder doesn't need to be cloned under GitLab. I'm not sure if I'm doing something incorrect as I followed all the necessary instructions under PytDev, EGit and GitLab.

**My GitLab project structure should be at least:**

src\geoHydro and the Python modules within the Python package directly under the GitLab project folder. Any help with the following will be appreciated.

Comment: I think the error lies somewhere around the "I created a new PyDev project" step. Please provide more details on this.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're creating a new project under that existing repository (so, it did what you asked, but that's not what you want, you'd want to write in the existing git dir, not in a new project in a subfolder -- it'd probably work if you specified the parent directory which already contained the geoHydro repository dir).

You can do the following with your current structure: delete the project from Eclipse (without deleting the contents), move all the contents from geoHydro/geoHydro to geoHydro, import the geoHydro project in Eclipse again (using File > Import > Existing projects into workspace) and commit the contents as they are now.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use neither PyDev nor EGit but maybe it would be a better option to open terminal, navigate to the folder of your project and execute following commands:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Some comment"
git remote add origin <remote repository URL>
git push -u origin master
```

remote repository URL you can obtain at GitLab for your repository.

Also, if you are not the only one developer working on project it is a bad practice to push IDE specific settings files and folders to VCS - so maybe think about to create an .gitignore file. There are many examples on internet of this files for python.

Comment: I think this approach can work well, but I disagree that it's a bad practice to push IDE specific settings to VCS (in this case `.project` and `.pydevproject`... it makes the life of other IDE users much easier later on without any real shortcoming (i.e.: why have everyone reconfigure the PYTHONPATH used for the project manually, expected python grammars to be checked, etc. if it could be pre-configured for you by having those files committed)?

Comment: Well it depends - if all developers within company use same IDE than maybe it is OK, otherwise if I use Sublime for example, I do not want to checkout .idea folder for example. Also, even though all developers use the same IDE, maybe I do not like a setup of other developer or vice-versa. So I belive that it is better that every developer set up project on his own.

Comment: I still don't agree (why would you be bothered by some file which would make someone else's life easier, even if it's a single developer -- I get that you don't care about it, but then again, you can just ignore that in your own workflow for all practical purposes).